# UNOCONV (Universal Office Converter) on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

How can I check the version of Unoconv on my Ubuntu 14.04?

I have tried `unoconv -v` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu 14.04 open the terminal and type:

```
apt-cache policy unoconv # also shows the latest available version (Candidate)
```

In Ubuntu 16.04 and later type:

```
apt policy unoconv
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command to list installed packages and search for `unoconv` in the results:

```
apt list | grep "unoconv"
```

Comment: unoconv/trusty,now 0.6-6 all [installed]
  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try executing:

```
$ unoconv -V #Uppercase
```

The output should be very similar to this:

```
unoconv 0.6
Written by Dag Wieers dag@wieers.com
Homepage at http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/

platform posix/linux2
python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 27 2010, 00:02:40)
[GCC 4.4.5]
OpenOffice.org 3.2
```

If this doesn't work, for newer versions, try with the following command:

```
$ unoconv --version
unoconv 0.7
Written by Dag Wieers <dag@wieers.com>
Homepage at http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/

platform posix/linux
python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
LibreOffice 5.1.6.2
```

By the way, if your `which unoconv` shows more than one `path` then use the path with the `unoconv --version` command to see which is what version.

Another important detail is that `unoconv` is really a `python` script, so, if you can search where is located you will be able to see the version inside of it, like in the `setup.py` file [here](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/blob/master/setup.py).

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you, unoconv -V gives me : unoconv: option -V not recognized, try unoconv -h for a list of all the options

Comment: In that case try with `unoconv --version`, this command works for the last version of the tool available through `apt-get`. I already added this to my answer. =)